# Specifying HostingEnvironment when running EF 7 migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-core

I have set my connection strings for my DbContexts as per my application environment. So in my Startup.cs I have

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment app)
{
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder(app.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", false)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

This configuration gets injected into my DbContexts as follows

```
public MyDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    var connString = Configuration.Get("SqlDb:ConnectionString");
    builder.UseSqlServer(connString);
}
```

And thus I can use my project in various environments as I please (by setting ASPNET_ENV in app or host settings)

However when I run ef migrations (for obvious reasons) I cant specify the HostingEnvironment at all, the startup class looks for a file called "config..json" since the environment name is missing. Is there a way around this or a workaround that I can do? For now whenever I run migrations I have to hardcode the connection strings when I run migrations

For interest sake I run migrations from powershell using the dnx . ef command

So in summary is it possible to specify my host environment via the command or do any other kind of workaround to specify my environment when running these commands?

Answer (score 1):

How migrations discovers services for migrations will be changing in upcoming versions of EF.

This is a WIP. See EF7's Wiki - [Design Meeting Notes (September 17, 2015)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes-(September-17,-2015)#design-time-services) and [Issue 2294](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2294)

Answer (score 0):

The `--environment` option was added with [7f48d0c](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/commit/7f48d0c0fca054ed70bebe0e8d2c58ee3cc3df9b).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work.  My `Startup.cs` has a method named `ConfigureDevelopmentServices` and when I run with Kestrel it correctly executes that method instead of `ConfigureServices`.  However, when I run `dnx ef migrations add Foo` it executes `ConfigureServices` instead.  Specifying `--environment Development` does not resolve the issue.